# SQLite3 run a trigger insert multiple times besed on inserted vlaue

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Want to run an insert n-times, the n is defined by inserted value on another table.
table 1:

```
create table Table1
(
    id              INTEGER default 1 not null
        primary key
        unique,
    name  TEXT not null
        unique,
    keys_number     INTEGER default 1 not null
);

table 2:
create table table_2
(
    id           INTEGER default 1 not null
        primary key
        unique,
    table_1_id INTEGER not null
        references table_1,
);
```

Now when i insert into table_1 like:

```
INSERT INT table_1 (name, keys_number) VALUES ('dummy_name', 5)
```

want to run a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_keys_after_insert_table_1
   AFTER INSERT ON table_1
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE table_1_id=new.id) < new.keys_number
BEGIN
INSERT INTO keys (table_1_id) VALUES (new.id);
END;
```

But this runs only once.

Finally, I want to have on table_2 values after the trigger

```
INSERT INT table_1 (name, keys_number) VALUES ('dummy_name_1', 5)
```

make the result like:

```
id;name;keys_number
1;dummy_name_1;5
```

and the result on table_2 after the trigger, should be

```
id;table_1_id
1;1
2;1
3;1
4;1
5;1
```

or if I insert another one on table_1

```
INSERT INT table_1 (name, keys_number) VALUES ('dummy_name_2', 2)
```

will make the result on table_1 like:

id;name;keys_number

```
1;dummy_name_1;5
2;dummy_name_2;2
```

and the trigger will give the result on table_2:
id;table_1_id

```
1;1
2;1
3;1
4;1
5;1
6;2
7;2
```

Comment: What is `keys` in `INSERT INTO keys (table_1_id) VALUES (new.id);`? Also check your 
last expected results. Are the 2 last rows correct?

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement you need a loop, which in SQL is implemented via a [recursive CTE](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursive_common_table_expressions).
Unfortunately [SQLite does not allow CTEs inside a trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html#limitations_and_caveats).

A workaround is to create a new table with only 1 column which will store the numbers 1 to the max expected value of `keys_number` in `table_1`:

```
CREATE TABLE table_numbers AS
WITH cte(keys_number) AS (
  SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT keys_number + 1 FROM cte WHERE keys_number < 100 -- change 100 to the max keys_number you expect
)
SELECT keys_number FROM cte
```

Now you can create your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_keys_after_insert_table_1 AFTER INSERT ON table_1
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_2(table_1_id) 
  SELECT NEW.id
  FROM table_numbers
  WHERE keys_number <= NEW.keys_number - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 WHERE table_1_id = NEW.id);
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=161bd1ae17c9feebc732becbd64abf15).